# Retrieve multiple lines of a column in a single row in Oracle 9i

Tags: oracle, oracle9i

Using Oracle 9i

Desc mtitem0 (table)

```
Materailcd          Char(10),
Technicalspecs   VarChar2(1000)
```

Query:

```
Select Materailcd, TechnicalSpecs
From Mtitem0
Where Materailcd  = '0100000121'

MATERIALCD TECHNICALSPECS
---------- ---------------------------------------
0100000121 INDUSTRIAL GRADE SALT
               SPECIFICATIONS:-
               A) MOISTURE  MAX: 4.0
                PERCENT BY MASS.
               B) MATTER INSOLUBLES IN WATER MAX:0.50
```

I want to retrieve the column 'TechnicalSpecs' in  a single line, like this:

```
MATERIALCD       TECHNICALSPECS
--------------------       ---------------------------------------
0100000121          INDUSTRIAL GRADE SALT SPECIFICATIONS:-  A) MOISTURE  MAX: 4.0  PERCENT BY MASS.
```

Please give me an idea and  help me in this regard .....

Regards
Rehaman

Answer (score 0):

i don't have access to oracle 9i but i belive below code will work. can you please try it and let me know

```
 select Materailcd     , ltrim(sys_connect_by_path(TechnicalSpecs,','),',') as staff
    from   ( select Materailcd
                  , TechnicalSpecs
                  , row_number() over (partition by Materailcd order by TechnicalSpecs) as seq
             from Mtitem0 )
    where  connect_by_isleaf = 1
    connect by seq = prior seq +1 and Materailcd = prior Materailcd
    start with seq = 1;
```

Comment: Hi Hijesh..thq's for responding....I have tried but not useful its giving error : ERROR at line 4: ORA-00904: "CONNECT_BY_ISLEAF": invalid identifier

Comment: okay. unfortunately i don't have oracle 9i environment  available to test it. but i am sure this logic will work. you may need to correct the query if there are any errors.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you have line feeds in your TECHNICALSPECS column. Just replace them by a single space.

```
Select Materailcd, replace(TechnicalSpecs, chr(10),' ') TechnicalSpecs
From Mtitem0
Where Materailcd  = '0100000121'
```

If its entered from a windows client you might have CR characters also so to be on the safe side remove those as well:

```
Select Materailcd, replace(replace(TechnicalSpecs, chr(10),' '),chr(13)) TechnicalSpecs
From Mtitem0
Where Materailcd  = '0100000121'
```